# Why does my bash script not run the .plt files?

Tags: bash, gnuplot

I made a bash script which is supposed to write the output of some rows from a file to another file then run some .plt (Gnuplot) files:

```
#!/bin/bash

SPATH="/home/ssh-jump/Adafruit_Python_DHT/examples"
cd $SPATH

cat $SPATH/dht22.txt |cut -d" " -f6,8,10 > $SPATH/test.txt
gnuplot $SPATH/2h.plt
gnuplot $SPATH/8h.plt
gnuplot $SPATH/24h.plt
gnuplot $SPATH/7d.plt
gnuplot $SPATH/1m.plt
gnuplot $SPATH/3m.plt
gnuplot $SPATH/1y.plt
```

If I'm right the script is supposed to:

- change to the given directory
- show the contents of the file from the given directory
- separate and write the content of rows 6, 8 and 10 to a file called `test.txt` in the same directory
- execute the given .plt files in the same directory

I enabled it through `chmod + x /path/of/script.sh` and checked ever file envolved with it, but it doesn't work. It doesn't update the `gnuplot` files, but it does update `test.txt`. Have I gotten something wrong?

**Edit:** With it doesn't work I mean that the script won't update the files. The `cat` command is supposed to update `test.txt` and `gnuplot .plt` files are supposed to update some .svg files on a website. Since I want this process to happen every 10 minutes I decided to make a script including both tasks and run a cronjob for it.

Comment: "but it doesn't work." -- in what way doesn't it work? What error messages (if any), do you get?

Comment: I don't get any. The script is supposed to update the gnuplot files so that they update some .svg files I included on a website. The cat command and gnuplot files update the files on the website separately.

Comment: If you are running it from your `crontab` you need to be aware that the PATH is not set the same as when you run a Terminal session. Try finding the path to `gnuplot` with `type gnuplot` and then setting your PATH correctly to include that at the top of the script.

Comment: the script it self is in the same directory written in the script and my cronjob is `*/10 * * * * /path/to/script.sh` you mean that I have to set the path of gnuplot at the top of the script as well?

Comment: Yes. Also, as you change directory to `$SPATH`, you can omit all the `$SPATH` stuff after `cd "$SPATH"` in your script, because you are already there.

Comment: I forgot that, thanks. I added the path to the beginning of the script with `PATH=/usr/bin/gnuplot:$PATH`. This is probably wrong since I looked up how to do it. The script didn't update the `gnuplot` files, however it updated `test.txt` file.

Comment: `$PATH` should contain _directories_, not files: `PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH`

Comment: Make sure that at the top of the *crontab* file, you have something like `PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin`. The meaning of this is to tell cron where the binaries/scripts that you call in your crontab are located.

Comment: In the script, you could just do `cd "/home/ssh-jump/Adafruit_Python_DHT/examples" || exit 1`, and then `cat ./dht22.txt  ... > ./test.txt` and `gnuplot ./foo.plt` etc.

Comment: Where is the script located? If in your home directory, make the PATH in the crontab file something like `PATH=</home/users/me>:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin`, where the part between angle brackets is that which you get when you run `echo $HOME` in a terminal.

Comment: Can I also do this with `crontab -e`? I get `/root` when running `echo $HOME`. Its like this`PATH=/root:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin` then. My script is located in my home so shouldn't I put the directory there like this `PATH=/home/ssh-jump/Adafruit_Python_DHT/examples:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin`?